# What is the difference between "-trager" and "-träger"?

Tags: difference

Why, for example, for hard disk, the translation is *Datenträger*, but the term *-trager* is used without umlaut in many other words?

Comment: Could you mention a word where it is _trager_? Nothing comes to my mind if I think about it. So I wonder, whether the premise of your question might be wrong. An example would clearify this. And: Hi and Welcome to German.SE!

Comment: The translation for hard disk is Festplatte, not Datenträger.

Comment: "Festplatte" - hard disk - is a kind of "Datenträger" - storage medium

Comment: "-träger" is a person or object that carries something. A Datenträger carries data. The first (and so far only) answer makes it clear that "-trager" has other meanings, although it is ultimately related to the verb "tragen". "Übertrager", for example, literally means "transferer", namely somebody who transfers a text from one language to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quote:**

> … but the term *-trager* is used without umlaut in many other words

**Answer:**

Well, since I could not think of such a word, I helped myself by searching for [*-trager*](https://www.dwds.de/?q=*trager) in the [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/) (*Digitales Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache*). This yields only one word: [*Übertrager*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/%C3%9Cbertrager), a technical term meaning *transformer*. A similar search for [*-träger*](https://www.dwds.de/?q=*tr%C3%A4ger) yields 167 words.

---

**Addition:**

User @RDBury pointed out in a comment that there were more findings for *-trager* in the DWDS User Database. However, I am afraid that most of these are false alarms. To check this, I took a closer look at the 59 findings from [*Die ZEIT*](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=%2Atrager&corpus=zeit&format=full&p=1&sort=date_desc&limit=50), the 12 findings from [*Der Tagesspiegel*](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=tsp&q=%2Atrager), and the 49 findings from [*Berliner Zeitung*](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=bz&q=%2Atrager).

There were only three cases that I would consider valid as they are derived from verbs: *Beauftrager* (someone who commissions someone or something), *Beantrager* (someone who makes a request), *Ertrager* (someone who endures something). I would not use these, because there are much more common words: *Auftraggeber* or *Beauftragender*, *Antragsteller* or *Beantragender*, and *Ertragender*.

All other cases appear to be—unless I missed some—typos in nouns (e. g., *Beauftrag[t]er*, *M<s>ä</s>[a]ndatstr<s>a</s>[ä]ger*, *Lehrbeauftrag[t]er*, *Nobelpreistr<s>a</s>[ä]ger*, *Tontr<s>a</s>[ä]ger*, …), typos in verbs (e. g., *getrag<s>er</s>[en]*, *ausgetrag<s>er</s>[en]*, …), or surnames (e. g., *Eisentrager*, *Leuchtentrager*, *Strager*, …).

Comment: The [DWDS usage database](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=%2Atrager&corpus=zeit&format=full&p=1&sort=date_desc&limit=50) turns up a few more. Some of these, like "Bruntrager" seem to be last names. But I also see *Eisentrager*, *Beauftrager*, *Ertrager*, *Bandltrager*, *Entscheidungstrage*, *Leuchtentrager*, and others.